# ipad app exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: iphone, debugging, ipad, fclose

My app exited abnormally with signal 11.  I don't know what that means.  There is no crash log and the debugger shows no error.  The app is just gone.

I got the following log.

```
Apr 27 21:31:31 unknown Apollo[1408] <Warning>: bring tab <VUIWebController: 0x2dcf30> to front
Apr 27 21:31:31 unknown configd[29] <Notice>: jetsam: kernel termination snapshot being created
Apr 27 21:31:32 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilemail[0x81d8]) Exited: Killed: 9
Apr 27 21:31:32 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.ihanghai.apollo[0x4f16]) Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:3795 (24506):0
Apr 27 21:31:32 unknown SpringBoard[33] <Warning>: Application 'Mail' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Apr 27 21:31:32 unknown com.apple.debugserver-50[1407] <Warning>: 1 [057f/1503]: error: ::read ( 4, 0x2ffc29f0, 1024 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)
Apr 27 21:31:32 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.ihanghai.apollo[0x4f16]) Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:3794 (24506):3
Apr 27 21:31:32 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.ihanghai.apollo[0x4f16]) Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:3202 (24506):10
Apr 27 21:31:32 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.ihanghai.apollo[0x4f16]) Working around 5020256. Assuming the job crashed.
Apr 27 21:31:32 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.ihanghai.apollo[0x4f16]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
Apr 27 21:31:32 unknown SpringBoard[33] <Warning>: Application 'Apollo' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11
Apr 27 21:31:33 unknown ReportCrash[1413] <Error>: libMobileGestalt loadBasebandMobileEquipmentInfo: CommCenter error: 1:45
Apr 27 21:31:33 unknown ReportCrash[1413] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copyInternationalMobileEquipmentIdentity: Could not get mobile equipment info dictionary
Apr 27 21:31:33 unknown ReportCrash[1413] <Error>: Saved crashreport to /Library/Logs/CrashReporter/LowMemory-2011-04-27-213133.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 0 egid: 0
Apr 27 21:31:33 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: crunchd[1414] Builtin profile: MobileMail (sandbox)
```

Does anyone know how to debug that kind of problem?

Answer (score 5):

I would also suggest looking at this post: [iPhone app crashes when launched from Xcode, but not from iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219532/iphone-app-crashes-when-launched-from-xcode-but-not-from-iphone)

The previous post mentioned advises setting NSZombieEnabled for this issue. Based on your description it may be an issue with already having this environment variable on and it causing low memory issues. You mention there is no crash log, that is exactly what happened to me when running with NSZombieEnabled - when I turned it off it these mysterious crashes stopped.

Comment: Thanks!, in fact my error was because i had a property of NSString set to assign instead of retain, but the zombieenabled variable prevented the app from crashing. However in the phone it would crash with segmentation errors